# Is the Heroic (default) highlight intro included when I choose random option?

Tags: overwatch

When selecting your [Highlight Intro](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Highlight_intros), if you pick the *random* option, is Heroic included?

I'm hoping it only includes the intros you unlock and the Heroic intro is excluded, but I get so few POTGs I'm too scared to actually test it out myself!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It includes all the intros you have unlocked, which includes the default one.

Comment: Well that's too high a risk for me to take!

Comment: Do you have anything to back that up?  Anecdotally I have all my heroes set to random highlight intro and have never once seen the Heroic intro for a hero that I've had another unlocked for.  Not to brag but I do get PotG fairly often so it statistically should have happened sometime.